# Getting error in browser console on using "externals" for excluding node_modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I am working in a react project. My project was not excluding node_modules while I was using "exclude: /node_modules". So I read some solved problems and added the below code to my webpack.config.js.

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
...
module.exports = {
...
target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs,     etc. 
externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in   node_modules folder 
...
};
```

My webpack.config.js then looks like this

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './dev/js/index.js'
    ],
    target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules
    module: {

        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

when I run my app, I get this error in console

[image: Browser Console]

How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think the line in the [documentation](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals) for `webpack-node-externals` is:

> When bundling with Webpack for the backend

This library is *not* meant to be used for bundles that run in the browser.  Only **backend** bundles running on node.

excluding `node_modules` in your loader should be sufficient to exclude unreferenced node_modules.  Otherwise, you *need* the referenced node_modules to be included in the bundle.

For the browser, you only want to exclude modules that will already be present on the page.  This can be useful if you are pulling react from a cdn, for example.  And you don't want to include all of react.js in your application bundle.

Comment: so should I remove it

Comment: yes, you shouldn't need this module for browser bundles.

Comment: But then why the browser console hot loader says 576 modules updated, everytime I make any change in component. Why is it updating so many modules everytime. This means node modules are also getting updated everytime. What should I do for this?

Comment: Exclude node_modules for the .scss loader as well.

Comment: No luck. Gives me the error when I add "exclude: /node_modules/" in .scss loader.